# html menu and sub menu active

Tags: javascript, html

I assign an active class in my menu, but the active class is not removed from the mobile menu, it always remains active. And also, if the subcategory is selected, I want the category itself to have an active class. I tried, I couldn't. Thank you in advance to the friends who helped.

For example, if category1.php page is open, "category" has the deactivated class.

```js
function updateMenu(url) {
const active = document.querySelector('.menu-item.active');

if (active !== null) {
    active.classList.remove('active');
}

const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item'));
    
links.forEach(function(li){
   let anchor = li.querySelector("a");
   if(url.indexOf(anchor.href) > -1){
       li.classList.add("active");
    }
});
    }
    
  updateMenu(window.location.href);
```

```html
<div class="header_side_container">
    <div class="header_builder_component">
        <nav class="main-menu">
            <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="home.php"><span>Home</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#"><span>category</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="Category1.php">
                                <span>Category 1</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="Category2.php">
                                <span>Category 2</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="gallery.php"><span>gallery</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="about.php"><span>about</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="contact.php"><span>contact</span></a>
                </li>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Mobil-->
<nav class="mobile_menu">
    <ul id="menu-top_menu-1">
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="home.php"><span>Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#"><span>category</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="Category1.php">
                        <span>Category 1</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="Category2.php">
                        <span>Category 2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="gallery.php"><span>gallery</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="about.php"><span>about</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="contact.php"><span>contact</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

[window.location.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/pathname) is the property you need. Once you have it, you can find the filename (last part of the whole pathname) by using `.substr` and `.lastIndexOf`.

In this code snippet, the *active* item is the parent of `JS`, I used that as an example since the `location.href` for these SO snippets is *https://stacksnippets.net/js*, hence the pathname is ***/js***, and finally, the filename is ***js***.

Check the code and you'll see what I mean

HIH

```js
function updateMenu(url) {
   const active = document.querySelector('.menu-item.active');

   if (active !== null) {
      active.classList.remove('active');
   }

   const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item'));
   
   links.forEach(function(li){
      let anchor = li.querySelector("a");
      
      if(anchor.href.indexOf(url) > -1) {
        const parentLI = $(li).parents('.menu-item').get(0)
        if(parentLI)
          parentLI.classList.add("active");
        else 
          li.classList.add("active");
      } 
   });
}

const pathname = window.location.pathname, filename=pathname.substr(pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);


updateMenu(filename);
```

```css
li.active > a span{
  font-weight: bold !important;
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header_side_container">
    <div class="header_builder_component">
        <nav class="main-menu">
            <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="home.php"><span>Home</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#"><span>category</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="Category1.php">
                                <span>Category 1</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="js">
                                <span>JS</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="Category2.php">
                                <span>Category 2</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="gallery.php"><span>gallery</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="about.php"><span>about</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="contact.php"><span>contact</span></a>
                </li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Mobil-->
<nav class="mobile_menu">
    <ul id="menu-top_menu-1">
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="home.php"><span>Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#"><span>category</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="Category1.php">
                        <span>Category 1</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="js">
                        <span>JS too</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="Category2.php">
                        <span>Category 2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="gallery.php"><span>gallery</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="about.php"><span>about</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="contact.php"><span>contact</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the active class is not deleted. Active remains in all li classes.

Comment: @MesutBla the `active` class doesn't have to be deleted from any list item (I didn't remove that first `if` because I didn't want to modify your function too much but it's not needed at all) you only need that `if` in case you are making an SPA which I think is not the case. if it's a traditional flow of reloading on each request, then the `active` class is *lost* on each reload. you only have to set it back to the correct item in the menu and that you can achieve by using the `window.location.pathname` prop. that behavior is diff to emulate in an SO snippet because there's no server work with